# TestNG Exception :com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

Tags: java, mockito, java-native-interface, testng, tdd

when running mockito test case getting exception as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:    com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

can anyone suggest me solution for this i tried some solution from stackoverflow but i did not get solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you paste your test and build configuration with dependencies?

Comment: If you have project build with Maven, By adding Dependency mentioned by @fl0w it will get solve this exception. But if you don't have maven project setup, You need to share more details of your Project Environment Setup.

Comment: i am not using maven project and in project lib there is testng file

Comment: @JaydeepBobade I suggest you to remove and reinstall that library again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure to inlcude the jcommander jar in your build path, for maven for example you can use the following code to do so:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
    <version>1.27</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: please check if the version of your lib actually contains the missing class " com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException" - if its not present try a different version of the lib.